# Flutterwave live - Invalid public key passed

Tags: android, payment-gateway, live, flutterwave

I integrated flutterwave PG in my android app.In sandbox the payment working fine.But now i changes the sandbox to live and have updated the live public and private keys.
But while checking the payment using my live card it shows Invaild public key passed error.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 4):

Please see how to get your live and test keys on the Rave by Flutterwave payment gateway: https://flutterwavedevelopers.readme.io/docs/api-keys

When on the live environment set `.onStagingEnv(boolean)` to false and vice versa when on the test mode.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into similar error. Found out that `isDebugMode` was set to `true`. Set it to `false` and problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to solve my problem